# Openpyxl Failing to write to xlsx

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am attempting to use openpyxl to write text information from batch experiments into excel files for analysis.

My most common error was "IndexError:At Least one Sheet must be visibile." When I try to coax the solution by manually naming the sheets, i get "BadZipFile: File is not a zip file"

The command ran in python is:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(exp_xlsx, engine = 'openpyxl') as writer: 
    if glob.glob(exp_xlsx) != []: # add "or ((overwrite != True) and (run_num == run_min)) 
        writer.book = load_workbook(exp_xlsx)  # open an existing workbook
        writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets) # copy existing sheets
        reader = pd.read_excel(exp_xlsx)# read existing file
```

and the file being read from is structed as such:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve exactly
***I am attempting to use openpyxl to write text information from batch experiments into excel files for analysis.** 
So why the writer?

Here you create a writer with the only `engine` as a param. So `exp_xlsx` is now a new workbook **With no Sheets** and any existing copy of the xlsx file that `exp_xlsx` refers to is overwritten.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(exp_xlsx, engine = 'openpyxl') as writer:
```

Hence the "IndexError:At Least one Sheet must be visible" error.

Here you are trying to open the just created empty workbook with no sheets so it will return a bad file error, the Error `"BadZipFile: File is not a zip file"`, since it not a saved xlsx file at this point.

```
  writer.book = load_workbook(exp_xlsx)  # open an existing workbook
```

Are your just trying to open the file `exp_xlsx` and load the data per the sample data in your question into a dictionary?

```
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets) # copy existing sheets

    reader = pd.read_excel(exp_xlsx)# read existing file
```